# Finding Duplicates In a column Except 0 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with Position varying starting from 0.
So I have to check whether the Position is having duplicate values except 0.As 0 can be present multiple times in my case.

```
if df['Position'].duplicated().any():
 print("Duplicate Positions found..Positions should be unique..Exiting")
```

This will check for unique values including 0.Is there any way I can exclude 0 while finding duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain mask by test for not `0` values by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Position':[0,1,2,0]})
    
if (df['Position'].duplicated() & df['Position'].ne(0)).any():
    print("Duplicate Positions found..Positions should be unique..Exiting")
```